# Maven surefire plugin doesn't include system-out in xml for passed tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, jenkins

I have an odd problem - I have a number of jUnit tests which produces logs to standard output and that's fine - those are printed into console an so forth. But for the integration part I need to include them in the `target/surefire-report/TEST-<class>.xml`. For failed tests there are both `<system-out>` and `<system-err>` but for passed tests both of those are missing. I've been struggling with this for two days now without any luck. There doesn't seem to be any property (except for `<redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>`, which works a bit differently and creates separate `-output` files, which are not picked by jenkins) that could solve this.

Comment: Why is the output relevant if the tests have passed? If you care about the output, it may be a sign that you don't have enough assertions in your test.

Comment: Simply for reference point. As a background - those won't be typical unit-tests but rather a more complex tests including communication with external server (yes, we are aware that this doesn't fit exactly but the basic setup works very wel, except for this missing log part)

Comment: @Wojtek did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @payne Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

If you mostly care about the report on Jenkins, this is generated by the [Jenkins JUnit plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit/), which has such an option:

> **Retain long standard output/error**: If checked, any standard output or error from a test suite will be retained in the test results after the build completes. (This refers only to additional messages printed to console, not to a failure stack trace). Such output is always kept if the test failed, but by default lengthy output from passing tests is truncated to save space. Check this option if you need to see every log message from even passing tests, but beware that Jenkins's memory consumption can substantially increase as a result, even if you never look at the test results!

The parameter (for use in a pipeline) is [`keepLongStdio`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/junit/)

For example

```
junit testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml', keepLongStdio: true
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to use the [redirectTestOutputToFile](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile) confguration item which is exactly for this purpose. but it will redirect to a separate file.

There you will find the output of stdout etc. `reportsDirectory/testName-output.txt`

Comment: ok, great, but as mentioned in the OP I'm aware of this option but it won't work as those file are not picked up by Jenkins and are not displayed...

Comment: By default they are not picked up but you can attach them to the build in jenkins. You can look into the workspace..

Comment: that's the question - how do I make them show on the result page of successful page?